# Add Subversion Repo

Tags: svn

I'm trying to connect to our existing subversion repository.
It is set up like so

repos (folder)
    Project1 (folder)
         conf  dav  db  format  hooks  locks  README.txt
    Project2 (folder)
         conf  dav  db  format  hooks  locks  README.txt

etc.

There are about 40 projects I'm trying to add to eclipse using Subclipse. But the I can't add the repos to the url due to a "Repository moved temporarily to '/repos'" error. I know it's there when I use the full project URL it works.

And I don't want to set up 40 seperate URLs to each specific project folder. It's going to be a hassel even after I set it up.

Thoughts?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you are trying to do can be accomplished through the Apache directive `SVNParentPath` which is discussed in this article: http://svnbook.red-bean.com/en/1.1/ch06s04.html

What you want to do is set the `repos` directory to become the `SVNParentPath`

Let me know if this helps.

Answer (score 0):

New subversion community site at http://subversion.wandisco.com also has some good info posted. As Daniel also states,the svn book also has the specifics around SVNParentPath